# RTK Query useMutation is missing "reset" method?

Tags: rtk-query

In the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#frequently-used-mutation-hook-return-values) it says that `useMutation` returns a tuple whose second value is the "mutation result" object, and that that object includes:

> `reset` - A method to reset the hook back to it's original state and remove the current result from the cache

But my hook isn't returning the `reset` method! I'm seeing the hook update with the returned data and everything, but there's no `reset` member.

Has anyone used this method? Is it maybe an error in the docs (since there is a `reset` member for `useQuery`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely there: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/637b0cad2b227079ccd0c5a3073c09ace6d8759e/packages/toolkit/src/query/react/buildHooks.ts#L926

Are you maybe using an old version of RTK? I think this was added with 1.8

Comment: Interesting, I have 1.6, so I'll try that!

Comment: is this method available in lazyQuery?